# Django – remove trailing zeroes for a Decimal in a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a way to remove trailing zeros from a `Decimal` field in a django template?

This is what I have: `0.0002559000` and this is what I need: `0.0002559`.

There are answers suggesting to do this using the `floatformat` filter:

```
{{ balance.bitcoins|floatformat:3 }}
```

However, `floatformat` performs rounding (either down or up), which is unwanted in my case, as I only need to remove trailing zeros without any rounding at all.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution is to use the `normalize()` method:

```
{{ balance.bitcoins.normalize }}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, perhaps because I am taking the values from a `.values()` queryset and not directly from the database.

Comment: Documentation for this is at https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?highlight=normalize#decimal.Context.normalize

Comment: I see the python documentation, but even when I grab a number directly from an object, this still isn't working for me in the Django template. The other solution does work.

Answer (score 6):

Try `{{ balance.bitcoins|floatformat:"-3" }}`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat:

> If the argument passed to floatformat is negative, it will round a
> number to that many decimal places – but only if there’s a decimal
> part to be displayed.

Comment: Please be advised the value `-3` must be in quotes for this to work: `{{balance.bitcoins|floatformat:"-3"}}` (I'm not able to edit this answer due to a character restriction).