# How to format the display of floats when using django-tables2?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am using django-tables2 to display some data. I have a column of floats and want them to be shown to just two decimal places (so, `10.238324` would be shown as `10.24`). Is there a simple way to do this? In Django templates, I do this using `{{number||floatformat:2}}`.

Potentially relevant docs:
http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html.

Comment: You still render it through the django template language, don't you? So why does `{{number||floatformat:2}}` not work?

Comment: @ascripter no you just render the entire thing using something like `{% render_table table %}` in the template. All the configuring is done in `view.py` or `table.py` before the table is sent in from the view's `context`. This is discussed in the tutorial: https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only have one column with floats, format your value in a [`render_<column_name>()` method](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods):

```
class NumberTable(tables.Table):
    number = tables.Column()

    def render_number(self, value):
        return '{:0.2f}'.format(value)
```

If you have multiple columns with floats, you can define a [custom column](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#subclassing-column) and reuse it:

```
class NumberColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        return '{:0.2f}'.format(value)


class NumberTable(tables.Table):
    temperature = NumberColumn()
    pressure = NumberColumn()
    flow = NumberColumn()
```

This custom column might also implement a custom constructor adding the number of decimals if that's something you want to vary.

Comment: Beautiful and it is there in the documentation not sure how I missed it. This will help me so much as I display my data!

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Round Your Data in the View

Actually that doesn't directly control the *display* of the number and will omit decimals for values that don't need them (`24.1` instead of `24.10`). It's a quick solution because it's your own view that you have to modifiy. It's not a good style however.

### 2. Replace the Template that django_tables2 renders

The docs say you can [use your own table template](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/template-tags.html#render-table)

The default template [(source code)](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/templates/django_tables2/table.html) contains blocks that you can override. I think that's the way to go. Your own `float_table.html` could look similar to this example:

```
{% extends "table.html" %} {# hope that finds the original template #}
{% block table.tbody.row %}
    <tr {{ row.attrs.as_html }}>
        {% for column, cell in row.items %}
            <td {{ column.attrs.td.as_html }}>{% if column.localize == None %}{{ cell|floatformat:2 }}{% else %}{% if column.localize %}{{ cell|localize }}{% else %}{{ cell|unlocalize }}{% endif %}{% endif %}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endblock table.tbody.row %}
```

This will apply the `floatformat` filter to every column that hasn't the [localize](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/localization-control.html) attribute defined. If you don't want to be more individual on the format you render each cell that seems to be the least intrusive way to get what you want.

If you want more granularity, it get's more difficult. Fine tuning of high level modules is rarely beautiful I think :)

### 3. Adding `<td>` or `<tr>` Attributes and format via javascript

Just for completeness and also not the way I'd recommend: The docs tell you how to [add custom attributes to rows or columns](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html). You can use this as a hook to add a class like `float2`. Via javascript (maybe also by CSS somehow?) you can then round the rendered content.

---

So I think option 2 is really the cleanest way to go. You can even simplify the template snippet not to check for the localization if it doesn't interest you.

I think it would be a nice feature for django_tables2 to have a hook for chaining template filters to a cell's content. Maybe you send them a feature request :)

Comment: Definitely if there is no simple way, then I will probablyl just do it in the view, because customizing tables like in your second suggestion seems too precarious for my simple tastes. However, I've found that in django-tables2 there are sometimes really simple ways to do things that are not documented explicitly, so I thought I would check as this seems a simple, common operation.

Comment: You just gave me the idea for option 3. But looking into the template code of the table, I really see so simple oneliner-hook to achieve what you want. I'd be glad to know if you discover sth. however.

Comment: we have a great example of what I was talking about, except I was wrong it is documented explicitly as discussed in Jieter's (now accepted) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`normalize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135464/django-remove-trailing-zeroes-for-a-decimal-in-a-template):

```
class DecimalColumn(tables.Column):
    '''Column to normalize decimals'''

    def render(self, value):
        return value.normalize()
```

usage:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    amount = DecimalColumn()
```